# Swift Structs Not Visible In Custom Framework

Tags: ios, swift, struct, frameworks

I'm trying to create a custom framework in Xcode. I've declared two structs, both public with public constants, but when I export the framework all I see defined is:

```
// Generated by Apple Swift version 3.1 (swiftlang-802.0.53 clang-802.0.42)

public var SWIFT_TYPEDEFS: Int32 { get }

public typealias char16_t = uint_least16_t
public typealias char32_t = uint_least32_t
```

It appears that the structs are not being included. I didn't initially follow it, but retracing my steps for those reading: I've performed the same steps as mentioned in [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorial).

How my swift struct is declared:

```
public struct APIRequest {
    public let domain = "http://example.com"

    public func makeRequest() {
        //Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you try `open` instead of `public`?

Comment: Do you have `import <FrameworkName>` somewhere in your code?

Comment: @AntonBelousov: The `open` modifier is only applicable to class declarations.

Comment: @XmasRights yes I am importing the framework. No compiler complaints there, just no structs visible inside it.

Comment: If the types I'm trying to expose are not Obj-C runtime compatible, could that be why they're not visible? Or is there a different project setting I'm missing to make it a pure Swift framework that is not Obj-C compatible ?

Comment: Everything looks sound to me - any chance you can stick it on Github, so we can have a look at the whole project?

Comment: @XmasRights I'll do that tonight. Was going to make it a cocoapod eventually anyway. 

Comment: @EricAya I'll remove it from the title once I can accept my own answer, but I have to wait 22 hours before SO will let me accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @XmasRight's suggestion to upload it to GitHub, I remade the framework from scratch just for the heck of it with a better name that won't collide with anyone else's future framework. In doing so I am now seeing the structs exposed in my compiled framework!

In the previous project I had renamed the project a few times and tweaked the bundle ID a few times while coming up with a name. It seems like maybe something didn't get copied over properly due to outdated names?